# Can I use create2 to deploy minimal proxies in solidity, without using assembly?

Tags: solidity-0.6.x, create2

Solidity 0.6.2 allows the creation of contracts with the `create2` opcode via the `new` keyword and passing a salt in addition to any args. This is adequate for creating standard contracts, but what if I want to deploy minimal proxies as per eip-1167? I can't see a way to pass in the creation bytecode for the proxy, with the template's address included. I know how I can do this with inline assembly, but it would be nice if I didn't have to!

Answer (score 1):

Not a proper answer but you should find that [openzeppelin-CLI](https://docs.openzeppelin.com/cli/2.6/deploying-with-create2) helpfull

```sh
npx oz create2 --query --salt 12345 --network development
```

On top of that, these links:

- [getting-the-most-out-of-create2](https://blog.openzeppelin.com/getting-the-most-out-of-create2/)
- [deep-dive-into-the-minimal-proxy-contract](https://blog.openzeppelin.com/deep-dive-into-the-minimal-proxy-contract/)